# Можно ли запустить Spring-приложение на удаленном хосте с локального?

Tags: spring, remote-debugging, remote

У меня есть какой-то удаленный хост, на котором я хочу запустить Spring-приложение, приложение лежит на локальном хосте, т.е. я хочу с локальной машины взять исходники и запустить на удаленной машине с возможностью дебага в локальное IDE. Как-то же в крупных компаниях делают дебаг(трассировка та же), не думаю, что у машин их сотрудников хватило вычислительной мощности. Мне интересно, как это делается?

P.S. Я предполагаю, что можно сделать два репозитория, один для прода, другой для дебага, т.е. коммитишь в дебаг репу, когда тебе нужно что-то проверить, дженкинс на удаленной машине, это видит, подсасывает изменения, запускает приложения, а я просто подключается через IDE, но выглядит немного костыльно.

Comment: Интересует решение для конкретного IDE? Или общий подход?

Comment: @RomanKonoval Ну лучше для IDEA.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Подключить IDEA к удаленному процессу, наверное, не проблема, меня скорее интересует, как бы правильно послать свои исходники.

Comment: Сделать это можно, но работать будет плохо. JPDA (протокол отладки JVM) не приспособлен для этого, очень медленно будет работать.

Comment: @RomanKonoval хм, как тогда в БОЛЬШИХ компаниях люди дебажат, не коммитят же сразу в свою ветку, ревьюить же будет невозможно.

Comment: Объемный вопрос, в комментарии не ответить. Практически никогда не приходится именно отлаживать на удаленном сервере. Удаленный сервер нужен  чтобы понять в чем проблема, если она есть только на удаленном сервере (используются логи и стектрейсы) чтобы ошибку локально воспроизвести. После этого если нужно отлаживается локально маленький тест, а не вся система.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112270/discussion-between-kaylil-01-and-roman-konoval).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать это несложно, но нужно иметь ввиду, что протокол JPDA, который используется для взаимодействия IDE и JVM, плохо оптимизирован для работы по сети (по крайней мере для java 8 и ниже) и работать сама отладка будет ну очень медленно.

В предположении, что у нас локально и на сервере у нас unix делается это так.

1. сборка артефакта, который можем запустить
2. копирование на удаленный сервер
3. собственно запуск
4. присоединение отладчика

### Сборка

Проще всего, конечно, использовать gradle или мавен и собрать uberjar. В IDE всегда есть возможность запустить сборку gradle или maven.

### Копирование

Тут можно использовать `scp`, `ftp` или `sftp`. Это будет одна команда типа такой (при условии, что сконфигурирована аутентификация с использованием ключей):

```
scp build/target/my-app.jar myuser@my.server.com:/home/myuser/my-app.jar
```

В IDE опять же есть возможность запустить команду или скрипт штатным способом. В Intellij:
[image: shell script in intellij]

### Запуск

Тут проще всего запустить команду через ssh, при этом создав еще и ssh-тунель:

```
ssh -L5005:localhost:5005 myuser@my.server.com 'java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar /home/myuser/my-app.jar'
```

Придется, конечно, решить несколько проблем:

1. нужно передать конфигурацию приложению. Тут зависит от реализации самого приложения. Или сначала сконфигурировать файл или файлы на сервере или передавать в переменных окружения или в system properties при запуске `java`.
2. приложение может требовать каких-то ресурсов, например, БД. Это нужно будет либо сконфигурировать заранее либо запускать не просто `java`, а более сложный скрипт.

### Отладка

В IDE выбираем вариант запуска `Remote Debug` и указываем соединяться к локальному хосту. Через ssh соединение будет происходить с удаленным хостом.

Comment: `rsync` еще вместо `scp` можно, чтоб если много файлов, слать только, что поменялось